# FormsBuilder Layout Editor all colors appear as black

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I'm using Forms versions 11.1.2.2.0 on centOs 6.10 system
I have o problem with Layout editor, all the colors appear as black

[image: Screenshot]

The problem is only in Layout editor when I deploy form it shows normal colors in web browser. The problem appeared today, yesterday everything was working just fine

Comment: So, what changed since yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen and was able to fix it by doing this.

Try navigating to "Edit > Preferences" then change "Color Mode:" from 'Editable' to 'Read Only - Shared'.  Restart your FormsBuilder application and see if the canvas is still black.

[Image of FormsBuilder Preferences Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRMmV.png)